# What is the name of this shape?

Tags: plane-curves

What is this shape called?

[image: Shape]

Comment: It probably doesn't have a specific name.

Comment: I too doubt that it is named, but $1+b+c+\frac{b \log (b)}{\log (2)}+\frac{c \log (c)}{\log (2)}+(1-b-c) (\log (1-b-c)+\log (\log (2)))=0$ looks to be a simpler form. How did you come across this oval?

Comment: It is called an egg.

Answer (score 4):

This would not fit in the comments

I think you may have made an error in your legend: by symmetry it is more likely to be something like 
$$(1-b-c)\log\left(\frac{1}{1-b-c}\right)/\log(2) + b\log\left(\frac{1}{b}\right)/\log(2) + c\log\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)/\log(2) - b - c - 1 = 0.$$

If so, this would be easier to read as $$(1-b-c)^{1-b-c} b^b c^c 2^{b+c+1} = 1$$ though that seems to have the real solution $b=c=1/4$ rather than your curve, so perhaps it should be something different.

Perhaps you could tell us the origin of your curve and the expression